# Columns change from integers to double when Importing into R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has 210 columns and 150K rows. Some of the columns in my data set are suppose to be integers but when I import the dataset into R those columns appear as double. I am not sure what the issue is ? I have used read_csv function and specified that col_names = TRUE. Am I missing something? Please guide me.

when I try to correct this using ceiling or floor, some of the values change by +/-1 and others stay the same which is not ideal.

Comment: Assuming you are using `read_csv` from the package `readr`. With the parameter `col_types` you can define the type of each column. See the manual for detailed explanation.

Comment: In response to @vinsfontecilla about the amount of columns. You can define also only a few columns by defining the `col_types` parameter as  `col_types = cols(name_integer_column = "i')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there are a lot of columns, is difficult to set the class/type from each one. Did you tried

```
round(...)
```

or maybe you can change the columns that are double with this:

```
for (col in colnames(data)) {
  if (is.double(data[,col])) {
    class(data[,col]) <- "integer"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is those three dots in round represent?

Comment: sorry i just meant using the round function